# Elastic Job failure : error - failed to determine members of SqlServerTarget

Tags: sql, azure, elasticsearch

I am working on Azure SQL Server. I've created an elastic job on the same server between 2 databases.

- SQL Server Agent : Elastic Job’s server
- Target database : original server, database

I've tried adding grant permission to the user.

My reference is: https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/azure-elastic-jobs-for-sql-databases/.

I get this error:

> Failed to determine members of SqlServerTarget (server name '******.database.windows.net', server location '******.database.windows.net'): Login failed for user 'UserForJob'.
> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 65536

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keMo5.png)

The process of creating a elastic job is detailed here:

```
-- Elastic Job’s server, database
create master key encryption by password = 'somepassword'
go

create database scoped credential JobExecution with identity = 'UserForJob',
secret = 'somepassword'
go

--USE master

create login UserForJobLogin with password = 'somepassword'

create user UserForJob for login UserForJobLogin with default_schema = dbo

-- Original server, database

create user UserForJob for login UserForJobLogin with default_schema = dbo

exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'UserForJob'

-- Elastic Job’s server, database

exec jobs.sp_add_target_group 'MyTargetGroup'

exec jobs.sp_add_target_group_member
'MyTargetGroup',
@target_type = N'SqlServer',
@refresh_credential_name = N'JobExecution',
@server_name = N'*****.database.windows.net'

EXEC [jobs].sp_add_target_group_member
@target_group_name = N'MyTargetGroup',
@membership_type = N'Include',
@target_type = N'SqlServer',
@refresh_credential_name = N'JobExecution',
@server_name = N'******.database.windows.net',
@database_name = N'database'

GO

EXEC [jobs].sp_add_target_group_member
@target_group_name = N'MyTargetGroup',
@membership_type = N'Include',
@target_type = N'SqlDatabase',
@server_name = N'*********.database.windows.net',
@database_name =N'*********_Stg'
GO

--Elastic Job’s server, database
exec jobs.sp_add_job
@job_name ='Get***',
@description ='Update ******'
go

--Elastic Job’s server, database

exec jobs.sp_add_jobstep
@job_name = 'Get****',
@credential_name = 'JobExecution',
@target_group_name = 'MyTargetGroup',
@command = 'IF EXISTS ( select * from sys.databases
            where name = ''******_Stg''
            )
            BEGIN
                exec Get*****
            END
            '

--Elastic Job’s server, database
exec jobs.sp_start_job 'Get********'
```

Comment: have you an account with that name on that server?

Comment: I've got a user named:"UserForJob" on my Target server. I don't have a user on my "Elastic Job’s server"

Comment: so change the name to the user you have on the elastic server, so hat the app can connect